# Accessing root properties in JavaScript objects from children

Tags: javascript

I have a block of JavaScript in which notably, `this.id` resolves to `undefined`.

The console indicates that `this` resolves to the `methods` object. I originally thought it would resolve to `item`. My question is, in my `buy` method, how do I access the `id` property. Please note, I do NOT want to move `buy` out of the `methods` object. I'm working to understand this.

```js
const item = {
  id: 5,
  methods: {
    buy() {
      alert('buying item ' + this.id);
      console.log(this);
    }
  }
};

const myButton = document.getElementById('myButton');
myButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  item.methods.buy();
});
```

```html
<button id="myButton">
Buy
</button>
```

Comment: _"I do NOT want to move buy out of the methods object"_.   Well, there's your problem...

Comment: `item.methods.buy.bind(item)()`

Comment: What if you have many items ( Looks like you are making a cart or something )? Are you going to add `methods` parameter to all of them ?

Comment: @Dilshan You are correct. Perhaps I'm taking a too "object-oriented" view on this. My thinking was to group types together to help keep things organized. `item` is really just a container I picked for this example. But, imagine a master object I want to share. That object will contain "Departments", "Products", "Customers". That is why I have a property and methods because I'm trying to have something like a namespace.

Comment: @Dev If you want to use OOP then try `es6` classes. The above code is really bad. `this` in JavaScript not act same as in other languages like Java. If you don't want to use es6 then you can use Webpack with babel compiler to convert your `es6` to `es5` code. And if you also need type definitions, you can try typescript, too,

Comment: You should read - https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/you-dont-know/9781491905142/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) as `item.methods.buy.call(item);` to bind `item` to `this`.

Try it below.

```js
const item = {
  id: 5,
  methods: {
    buy() {
      alert('buying item ' + this.id);
      console.log(this);
    }
  }
};

const myButton = document.getElementById('myButton');
myButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  item.methods.buy.call(item);
});
```

```html
<button id="myButton">
Buy
</button>
```